# Cronbach's alpha, by Category, in New Column in SAS

Tags: sas, correlation

I am new in SAS and I am trying to calculate Cronbach's alpha. The code I am using is:

```
proc corr data=test alpha;
   var A B C;
 run;
```

However,

1. This way I only get the Cronbach's alpha in a table in the results section. Is there a way by only using the editor, to automatically get a new column in the dataset with the value of the Cronbach's alpha coefficient?
2. Is it possible to calculate the Cronabch's alpha for the variables A, B, and C, but per group? So for instance if in my dataset I have 100 groups, would it be possible to calculate the coefficient of Cronbach's alpha per group, in one go and not by creating 100 different datasets?

Comment: 1 I don't know proc corr, but most of the time you can't do all at once with sas, you have to join your data together in another step. 2 Have you tried `by varGroup;` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok folks I've found it. Many thanks @user456789123 for helping me with 2.

So the code I used:

```
   proc sort data=test;
     by varGroup;
   run;
```

Which will help in step 2. that I will need to get the Cronbach's alpha for each Group.

```
proc corr data=test alpha outp=stats;
   var A B C;
   by varGroup;
 run;
```

Here I get 'x' number of tables in the results section, with the Chronbach's alpha depending on how many categories the varGroup has. Also the command `outp=gg` actually creates a table with all the categories, Cronbach's alpha coefficients per category, and a bunch of other info produced by the `proc corr` procedure which I can drop later.

So last thing to do is to merge the new table "stats" with the old table "test" by the "varGroup" variable and I get the original table I was looking for.